# How to restrict user to purchase new In-App Purchase Product while it is being review by Apple?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am adding couple of new In-App Purchase Products to my existing App(Available on App Store).
These Products are shown in my App through web service.Now, I want to show a message to users that these items are not available for sale while reviewing these products by Apple. Is there any API for it and If I does't show these new Products in my app while review by Apple. will Apple approve my In-App Purchase products? .... suggest me.

Regards,
Pankaj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is (unfortunately) no interface in iTunes Connect to determine if in-app purchases have passed the review process: you will need to set up an option in your web service that filters out products that have not yet been approved, and then once they pass through the review process you can make them available to the app.

Comment: Hi Femi, If I do so as you say, then the new products will not be available in my App for Apple also while reviewing. Will Apple approve my In-App Purchase products?

Comment: Ah. That one I'm honestly not sure about: I'm assuming they would approve the products but you might want to spend one of your support incidents on verifying that.